# Unable to send files using netcat

Tags: shell, networking, proxy, netcat

I am using netcat to send file over my campus network.
I have used

c:\nc -w200 10.x.x.x 9638 < file.txt

on my client machine and

c:\nc -v -L -p 9638 >> nc.out

on my computer that is working as a server to receive files.
It worked completely fine when i tested it using localhost hence sending and receiving files on my system only.I am using the netcat version without the GAPING_SECURITY_HOLE downloaded from http://www.rodneybeede.com/Compile_Netcat_on_Windows_using_MinGW.html.

Our systems are connected to the net using proxy servers. Could they be interfering? Also pinging computers is disabled.
I am working on windows for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes proxy and router may interfere. 
Try to see if you can telnet to that port

```
telnet <ip> port
```

That will tell you if you can access that machine on that port

Comment: It wasn't working earlier but now its working ... the proxy was not an issue... and yes i was able to telnet. thanks for the quick reply